# Cant Get program to print the files at the end of line

Tags: bash, unix

trying to get the size of the file printed on the end of line.

this is the code i have.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#

find /home/clf18ftf -type f \( -size -100c -o -size 
+1000c \)
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus
/home/clf18ftf/WebTech/Assignments/Assignment2/css/myStyle.css
/home/clf18ftf/WebTech/Assignments/Assignment2/css/.DS_Store 100 bytes

Answer (score -1):

According to manual of find:

```
find /home/clf18ftf -type f \( -size -100c -o -size +1000c \) -printf "%h/%f %s bytes\n"
```